# How to retrieve custom object from c# hashtable?

Tags: c#, timer, hashtable

I have a Hashtable that I am trying to store a system Timer object in. How can I access the Timer by its key and use its methods? Is there a way to cast an object to a timer?

```
Hashtable example = new Hashtable();


public void test ()
{
    System.Timers.Timer newTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    example.Add("test", newTimer);
    example["test"].Start(); //error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you use `HashTable` at all? Use a generic `Dictionary<string, System.Timers.Timer>`:

```
Dictionary<string, System.Timers.Timer> timers = new Dictionary<string, System.Timers.Timer>();
 
public void test ()
{
    System.Timers.Timer newTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timers.Add("test", newTimer);
    timers["test"].Start(); 
}
```

Of course you could also simply cast the Object in the `HashTable` to `System.Timers.Timer`, but in 99% the `HashTable` is obsolete. So with your code above you had to cast it:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = example["test"] as System.Timers.Timer;
timer?.Start(); // the ? ensures that the code works even if the type is not a Timer, it simply skips it
```